# Objective-C Blocks, Recursion Fails

Tags: objective-c, ios, closures, objective-c-blocks, block

Sup guys,

I'm trying to do a function that calls itself but by putting everything on one block,

As you can see, the following function is intended to be called an indefinite amount of times (until arcrandom returns a number lower than 50) and you should expect as an output a variable number of "RUNNING" messages, depending on chance.

```
void (^_test_closure)(void) = ^ {
    NSLog(@"RUNNING");
    if(arc4random() % 100 > 50) {
        _test_closure();
    }
};

_test_closure();
```

However, when running it, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error and the reason I've found is that when the code tries to calls _test_closure inside of the closure it basically points to nowhere.

Does anyone know how to make the above code work?

Comment: Clang should give you a warning with this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recursion and blocks is tricky. Because a block captures all variables passed in, the variable `_test_closure` is not initialized yet (and clang should give you a warning:

> Block pointer variable '_test_closure' is uninitialized when captured by block

).

There are several ways you can get around this, but the most obvious & simplest is to just make the block itself a `__block` variable (what @H2CO3 said). This allows the block to be `weak-linked` almost, so that when you call it again, it is properly initialized.

Another option you have is making the block a global or static, like this:

```
// outside of 'main', thus being a global variable
void (^blockRecurse)(int) = ^(int level) {
    if (level < 0)
        return;
    NSLog(@"Level: %i", level);
    blockRecurse(--level);
};

int main()
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        blockRecurse(10);
    }
}
```

This means it's not being captured by the block, but instead it's referencing the global / static variable, which can be changed by all code equally.

Comment: Of course, if it's a global, you're not really gaining any benefit over simply defining it as a regular function. One beauty of blocks is that they can be defined inline inside another function (with closures, even) if the logic is only needed in one place.

Comment: @chaiguy undoubtedly true. It was, however, one simple alternative to capturing the block by reference using `__block`.

Answer (score 8):

You have to declare your block itself as a block variable:

```
__block void (^_test_closure)();


_test_closure = ^{
    NSLog(@"Running...");
    if ((arc4random() % 100) > 50) {
        _test_closure();
    }
}

_test_closure();
```

Comment: This just leads to a retain cycle. You get the warning:
"Capturing '_test_closure' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle"

Comment: @Shane: This answer was probably written prior to ARC, in which case there would be no retain cycle here.

Comment: @LeszekŻarna: your answer is the same as this one.

Comment: @newacct I tested this answer and had warnings in Xcode, so it is not the same.

Comment: @LeszekŻarna: so? sometimes there's warnings, sometimes there isn't. But both have a retain cycle. Yours is worse because it adds another variable for no reason.

Comment: @newacct My answer has no retain cycles, has it ? So I do not understand why are you critical to that. Could you provide working answer ?

Comment: @LeszekŻarna: the block captures `block1recursive`, a strong reference which points to the block itself. So the block has a strong reference to itself.

Answer (score 2):

It works with XCode 5 - no warnings, no retain cycles:

```
typedef void(^blockT)();

blockT block1;
blockT __block block1recursive;

block1recursive = block1 = ^(){
    block1recursive();
};

block1();
```