# Wrapping a block with itself

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I was tempted to write code like this one day...

```
- (void)myMainMethod {
    [self doSomethingWithCompletion:^{
        NSLog(@"My original completion block");
    }];
}

- (void)doSomethingWithCompletion:(CompletionBlock)completion {
    if (self.someBoolValue) {
        completion = ^{
            NSLog(@"My wrapper completion block");
            if (completion) completion();
        };
    }
    [self someMethodThatTakesACompletion:completion];
}

- (void)someMethodThatTakesACompletion:(CompletionBlock)completion {
    if (completion) completion();
}
```

It seemed to be work fine but I'm not 100% sure if it's safe. Creating a new block to wrap the old one is always an option but part of me appreciates the simplicity of this approach.

I'm especially curious HOW this even works at all.

By the way, the output of this code is...

```
My wrapper completion block
My original completion block
```

Comment: You might want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133907/objective-c-blocks-recursion-fails

Comment: @ujell Thanks, but that still doesn't answer why it works. What I am attempting is not recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two `completion` variables:

- The method parameter, which is a regular local variable.  Let's call this "Outer Completion".
- The variable inside of the block, which is essentially an instance variable of the block object.  Let's call this "Inner Completion".

It works because these two variables are completely separate from one another.

When the block is created, Inner Completion is assigned the value of Outer Completion.  After the block has been created, Outer Completion is assigned to a new value. This will not affect the value of Inner Completion.

It's essentially the same as this:

```
NSString* foo = @"there.";
foo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@", foo];
```

Note that it would not work if `completion` were declared as a `__block` variable.  In that case, changing the value of Outer Completion would affect the value of Inner Completion.

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out answer. So the way I understand it is that the original block is copied into the new block. The original block is then replaced by the new block. Using `__block` would prevent the copy thus creating a block that called itself resulting in infinite recursion.

Comment: @CrimsonChris The block isn't copied.  There are two different variables that initially point to the same block instance.  Changing the value of one variable doesn't affect the value of the other variable.  E.g.: `a = completion; b = a; a = nil;`  `b` still points to `completion`.

Comment: I guess what I meant was that the _reference_ to the original block is copied and captured by the wrapper block, forming a strong relationship between the wrapper block and the original block. Then the reference to the original block is pointed to the newly created wrapper block.